# Lost of lengthy integers when inserting Excel VBA SQL to Access database by

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, double, adodb

I have a csv containing lengthy numbers (like 3-4 billions) which i would like to insert them into access database through ADOBD sql in excel. The code works through but all these numbers become empty when i open the Table in the Access database.

I have double checked in the Designed View in Access that the data type is "Double" in the access and I have no clue why the lengthy intergers will be lost. Can I ask for your guidance on this please? The code has been simplified but the key point is how i could do something on the INSERT INTO line to force it reading lengthy numbers into access database? Many thanks.

```vb
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim MyConn
Dim strSQL, strSQL2, strSWL3 As String
Dim InsertDate As Date
Dim FileDate As String

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
MyConn = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
With cnn
  .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
  .Open MyConn
End With

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT [Date] FROM [Text;DATABASE=C:\].[Source.csv];", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Daily] "
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT [Date] As WDate, Code, [#Sold] As QtySold"
strSQL = strSQL & "  FROM [Text;DATABASE=C:\].[TargetDB.csv]"
cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.Execute

Set cmd = Nothing
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
```

Comment: Values below 2^31 get inserted? Problem may be the select from a csv where the field is casted as long. Try convert it to double in select statement with `SELECT [Date] As WDate, CDbl(Code), [#Sold] As QtySold`asuming`Code`is the problematic field..

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment... i tried and it returned error saying "Invalid use of NULL". guess i need to add a little bit more on top of CDbl()? Can also try other things like CAST or CONVERT or NZ?

Comment: If`Code`can be NULL`CDbl`will fail. Fix with`CDbl(Nz(Code,0))`.